# ¿Cómo poner 2 variables en unas sola variable de sesiones en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo 2 variables que vienen de JS con JQUERY por medio de url, la una es la ID de un producto y la otra la cantidad que se ingresa ahora tengo que ponerla todo esto en una sola variable de sesiones digamos `$_SESSION['producto']` para después usarla en un bucle `FOR` como ejemplo estaría así

var p=id del producto  y c=cantidad  es la variable que viene de js de un botón y de un input numérico

```
  if(isset($_GET['p'])){
  //no se si esto s puede hacer ponerlo en forma de array
  $_SESSION['producto'][]= $_GET['p'];
   $_SESSION['producto'][]= $_GET['c'];


  for($i=0; i< count( $_SESSION['producto']); $i++){
    echo   $_SESSION['producto'][$i][0];//que me de el id
    echo   $_SESSION['producto'][$i][1];//que me de la cantidad
   }
```

No sé, se me ocurre algo así o como debería tratar esto para que cuando se ejecute el bucle no me de valores nulos o vacíos

Comment: José mira [este tutorial](http://programacion.net/articulo/crear_un_carrito_de_compra_ajax_con_jquery_y_php_1476) en castellano explicando un carrito de compra completo, creo que será de mucha utilidad. Explica los diferentes elementos y como usarlos. Más adelante podrías implementarlo mediante clases (Programación Orientada a Objetos). Esto te dará nuevas perspectivas y te facilitará todo, aunque al principio cuesta un poco entenderlo... pero cuando lo has entendido, vas sobre ruedas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo recomendar primeramente que uses nombres de variables con sentido que ilustren perfectamente para que las vas a emplear, nombres como a, b, c , etc son indescriptibles no importa en el contexto que los uses, por eso te cambie los nombres: p seria "producto" y c: "cantidad". Ahora puedes hacer lo siguiente para ver lo que tienes en tu carrito usando la sessión en este caso es para actualizar el carro, tanto para agregar un nuevo producto como para actualizar el monto de uno que ya tienes almacenado.

```
if(isset($_GET['cantidad'])){
   $carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
   $carrito[$_GET['producto']] = $_GET['cantidad'];

   $SESSION['carrito'] = $carrito;
}

$carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
foreach($carrito as $producto => $cantidad){
  echo "Producto: ".$producto.', cantidad: '.$cantidad;
}


/*El arreglo de la sessión tendria la siguiente forma*/
SESSION => (
    'carrito' => (
       2 => 12,
       3 => 4,
       4 => 1,
       5 => 2
    )   
)
```

Donde el primer elemento seria 2 el id del producto y 12, su cantidad y asi sucesivamente, con el ciclo foreach te será más facil recorrer el carrito.